# Name resolution of inner classes in Java

Tags: java, jenkins, scope, inner-classes

I'm currently trying to make a plugin for Jenkins CI. I'm trying to create a new Project type and I'm running into some issues with compiling my code. I see the following work in the Jenkins code base:

```
// hudson/model/AbstractBuild.java
package hudson.model;
public abstract class AbstractBuild<P extends AbstractProject<P,R>,R extends AbstractBuild<P,R>> extends Run<P,R> implements Queue.Executable {
    public abstract class AbstractBuildExecution extends Runner {
        // ...
    }
}

// hudson/matrix/MatrixBuild.java
package hudson.matrix;
public class MatrixBuild extends AbstractBuild<MatrixProject,MatrixBuild> {
    public class MatrixBuildExecution extends AbstractBuildExecution {
        // ...
    }
}
```

These two files compile fine. When I try to do the same in my plugin...

```
package parallelbuild;
public class ParallelBuild extends AbstractBuild<ParallelProject,ParallelBuild> {
    public class ParallelBuildExecution extends AbstractBuildExecution {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Maven gives me the following error from javac.

```
[ERROR] /home/jsternberg/jenkins-parallel-build/parallel-build/src/main/java/parallelbuild/ParallelBuild.java:[29,48] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class AbstractBuildExecution
[ERROR] location: class parallelbuild.ParallelBuild
[ERROR] /home/jsternberg/jenkins-parallel-build/parallel-build/src/main/java/parallelbuild/ParallelBuild.java:[29,48] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class AbstractBuildExecution
[ERROR] location: class parallelbuild.ParallelBuild
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your POM using a version that contains AbstractBuild having an inner AbstractBuildExecution class?

Just saying because there's at least one version of AbstractBuild (1.312) that doesn't have it.

Comment: Probably obvious to normal Java developers, but I did not even consider that I was using an old version of the dependency. The one chosen automatically when you create a project is 1.424 (which upon checking out that version, does not seem to have AbstractBuildExecution).

Comment: if normal=expecting that _anything_ can go wrong, then yeah, its obvious :)